# Flexmix R: Mixture regression with distinct component variables

Tags: r, variables, components, regression, mixture

I was setting up the following exemplarely mixture of regression model using the flexmix package in R: `model = flexmix(y~ x1 + x2 +x3, data = Data, k=2, control = list(verb = 5, iter = 1000))` How can I decide to drop one variable in one of the components, so that I mix `y~x1+x3` in component 1 with `y~x2+x3` in component 2?

Comment: Do you mean dimensionality reduction such as PCA ?

Comment: There are many ways to iteratively switch out independent variables -- perhaps check out the `leaps` package?